# Javascript SlideDown Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem that I have been despairing about for days now, I hope you can help me.

I have built a slide down content into my page.
It consists of several adjacent images that open a slide down content when you click on one of them.
This works quite well so far. But now, when one content is open and I click on the other image to open the other content, the new content opens first and then the old one closes.

But it should first close the old content and then open the new one.
I hope you can help me or give me tips or directions on what the problem is or how I should do it so that it works.

best regards Rick

Javascript

```
 const covers = document.querySelectorAll('.coverflow1');

  covers.forEach((cover, index) => {
    cover.addEventListener('click', () => {
      setAsActive(index);
    });
  });

  function setAsActive(activeIndex) {
    const coverflow = document.querySelector('.cover1');
    coverflow.setAttribute('active', activeIndex);
    
    covers.forEach((cover, index) => {
      if (index === activeIndex) {
        
        cover.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        cover.classList.remove('active');
      }
    });
  }

 

  function hideAllContents() {
    const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.cover1, .slide-down-content, .slide-down-content1, .slide-down-content2, .slide-down-content3, .slide-down-content4 , .slide-down-content5 , .slide-down-content6 , .slide-down-content7 , .slide-down-content8 , .slide-down-content9');
    for (const content of contents) {
      content.classList.remove('show-content');
      content.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  
  
  function toggleSlideDown(element) {
    hideAllContents();
    
    const content = document.querySelector('.slide-down-content');
    if (element.classList.contains('active')) {
        
    } else {
        
        element.classList.add('active');
        content.classList.add('show-content'); 
    }
  }

  function toggleSlideDown1(element) {
    hideAllContents();
    const content = document.querySelector('.slide-down-content1');
    if (element.classList.contains('active')) {
      element.classList.remove('active');
      content.classList.remove('show-content');
    } else {
        element.classList.add('active');
        content.classList.add('show-content');
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div ><img src="image/sonstiges.webp" class="SGP" alt="Gemuese"></div>
    <div class="coverflow1" data-coverflow="1">
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown1(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown2(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown3(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown4(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown5(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown6(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown7(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown8(this)"></div>
        <div class="cover1" style="background-image: url('image/.webp');" onclick="toggleSlideDown9(this)"></div>
        
    
      </div>
      <div class="slide-down-content">
        <div id="tableDiv">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td class="tbName1">Name:</td>
                <td class="tbOrt1">Ort:</td>
                <td class="tbDis1">Entfernung</td>
              </tr>
             
                </td>
                
              </tr>
```

CSS

```
 .coverflow1 {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: left;
    height: 100px; /* Höhe Ihrer Coverflow */
    perspective: 100%; /* Einstellung für die Perspektive */
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    background-image: url(../image/brett1.webp); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 3px 68px;
    background-size: 98%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    
    
  }  

  

  .cover1 {
    
    flex: 0 0 25%; /* Breite der einzelnen Coverbilder */
    height: 100px; /* Höhe der einzelnen Coverbilder */
    margin: 0 4%; /* Platz zwischen den Bildern */
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    scroll-margin-left: 10px;
    
    
  }

  
  .active {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateZ(0px);
    
    /* Ändern Sie die Skalierung und Z-Übersetzung nach Bedarf, um das aktive Element hervorzuheben */
  }


  .slide-down-content {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 1s ease;
    }
    .slide-down-content1 {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 1s ease;
    }
```

i tried some things but the result was always the same, i also experimented a lot with bard and GPT but they couldn't really help me either, the code didn't break with their help but it always opened the new content before the old one was closed

Comment: [Please don't add phrases like "HUGE PROBLEM" to your title/question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). You won't get answers any faster. Instead provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (preferably via [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) to help people understand your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).